# Problem updating Kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, updates

When I run `apt update` on my kali terminal, I get this error -

> E: The repository 'https://http.kali.org/kali sana Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: This isn't a question about information security and belongs on [su] instead.

Comment: Compulsory link - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: Run this:  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove  and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because Kali Sana is an End-Of-Life Kali release. You should use the Kali Rolling repositories.

Use the following command to update your `sources.list`:

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade
```